# At what level should security be implemented in a social network web application?

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication

I am developing a social web application in php/mysql, I would like to hear your advice about what would be a better way to implement security. I am planning something like this:-
At the presentation level, I restricting the user to see only those items/content he is eligible to see with the rights he is eligible 
& 
at the database level, whenever my data is read/ written or updated I verify that the person has rights to such interactions with that part of data.
So for each action there is 2 layers of security one at the view level & another at the database level.
Would double checking be much overhead ?

ofcourse this handles only with the internal security issues ..

Comment: You are actually referring to "permissions" - not security.

Comment: I agree with Mario,  security isn't something you just "add on".

Comment: sorry i am newbie thus not very expert.. :)

Comment: It seems you have a plan (sounds ok). But you could show us the permission API you thought of or might want to implement. It would be easier to comment and advise on that.

Comment: i donot understand what exactly you mean by permission api, but if you meant the exact model of how permission system works, this is how i m planning : the prsentation layer would use the identity of the user(userID) to determine what extent of interactions he is eligible for making with a specific piece of content(contentID), and would show only those interaction possibilities for that piece of content. ...continued

Comment: When the certain interactions are made with the presented content, and the controller layer called certain functions existing in the business layer to interact with the content,then the functions(business layer) would again check whether the user is eligible to interact in this manner with the content piece. In case he is not, he will be disallowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who knows about the current user?

If the business layer *does not* know who the current user is, it cannot do any access control. Rather the presentation must ask the authorization component each time whether a specific user is allowed to perform a particular action. This is O.K. if the presentation layer basically executes some well defined use cases.

If the business layer *does* know who the current user is, it might ask the authorization component itself on calls that reach from the presentation layer into the business layer. However, this introduces a lot of redundant checks. This is O.K. if the presentation layer does a lot of nifty things with entity objects of the business layer or when security is critical.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually thinking of making checks at both the presentation and business layer. I think checking at presentation layer does not solve the problem completely since a user ineligible for a certain content might be able to access the content that he cannot see a normal way to access but he knows the link for that..

Comment: @Rajkumar Gupta Invoking use cases based on the URL is part of the presentation. The difference I was talking about is: does the controller who invokes the use case, check authorization, or does the use case do it on its own. If either of this is done (properly), the user cannot access a URL that he is not authorized to.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the permissions model I recommended using [Mandatory Access Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) because its takes groups into consideration.  ([RBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) is another model worth noting,  but it doesn't have groups.)

But at the end of the day security is really a code quality control problem.  You could implement the most hardened RBAC and it be completely bypassed by a single XSS/XSRF/SQLi vulnerability.